# Batch file fails with chcp 65001

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am finishing up a backup script for my peers to use while at work and I need assistance.

We are brazillian and as such, files and paths will be in Portuguese. This means I need Unicode characters like é, á, à, ç and the likes. For example: `C:\Users\Usuário\Área de Trabalho` is a valid path.

If I open up a command prompt and type like that, it will accept the characters accordingly. However if I try to use the same characters in a batch script, I get strange characters.

In both cases, if I open up a command prompt and type `chcp`, I get as response that it's using `codepage 850`. If I put `chcp` onto a batch file and run it, it gives the same response. So, in running a `cmd` instance or a batch, the codepage used is the same, but the characters accepted are not.

If I open up `cmd` or put in a script `chcp 65001` (codepage of UTF-8), as soon as I type anything Unicode and press enter it closes the prompt window. I tried for example typing just `echo é` and it was enough to crash `cmd`.

I need to be able to read/write data with those characters.
I am using Sublime Text to code.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74942/discussion-on-question-by-rafael-umbelino-batch-file-fails-with-chcp-65001).

Comment: Are you writing the script in the UTF-8 encoding?